# Unable to create a folder properly

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api, mime-types

According to https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/folder I just have to specify correct MIME type. But:

```
metadata = Google::Apis::DriveV2::File.new title: "test",
  content_type: "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
  parents: [{id: "0B0l....BUmM"}]
p service.insert_file(
  metadata,
).mime_type
```

creates `"application/octet-stream"` instead of folder.

`google-api-client (0.9)` in Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `mime_type`, not `content_type`.